# T-SQL: why sp_executesql requires it's parameters types?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wonder why does `sp_executesql` require to tell exactly all its parameter types (`@params`).

```
sp_executesql [ @stmt = ] statement  
[   
  { , [ @params = ] N'@parameter_name data_type [ OUT | OUTPUT ][ ,...n ]' }   
     { , [ @param1 = ] 'value1' [ ,...n ] }  
]
```

Because every time a user passes parameters - every parameter has its own type already that (I hope) may be determined inside stored procedure without explicit description?

Comment: `sp_executesql` runs in a separate context so all `query` parameters should be declared in this context.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev may you clarify this? Do I understand correcty that sp_executelsql - is stored procedure, how it's parameters are declared? What type has param1 .. paramN ?

Answer (score 3):

`sp_executeSql` is a procedure to execute dynamic SQL statements. 
It has no definitions for whatever parameters are used in the statement it's executing - so you must supply these definitions just like you would with any other SQL statement using parameters.
If you wouldn't send the parameters definition, the SQL Server engine would not have any way of knowing how to treat the parameters in the dynamic SQL statement.

From [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments):

> **Note**
>   @stmt can contain parameters having the same form as a variable name, for example:
>   `N'SELECT * FROM HumanResources.Employee WHERE EmployeeID = @IDParameter'`
>
> Each parameter included in `@stmt` must have a corresponding entry in both the `@params` parameter definition list and the parameter values list.

Comment: Thank you, but if sp_executeSql is a procedure, what type @param1..N have? How this procedure is declared?

Comment: It's a system procedure. Its internals are unknown. It executes a textual SQL statement, just like SQL Server Management Studio executes your "normal" SQL statements. In the documentation fragment you provided, I agree that the parameters are badly matched. The parameters (`@param1`, ...) should match the parameter declarations (`@parameter_name data_type [ OUT | OUTPUT ][ ,...n ]`). Alex Kudryashev already provided a concrete example using parameters `@id` and `@val`.

Comment: Thank you, @BartHofland. Is it possible to declare stored procedure with parameters that may accept value of any datatype just like sp_executeSql for param1 .. paramN ?

Comment: Not directly. I'm guessing it's possible to do something similar using CLR, but I have no experience with that.

Comment: Hmmm, I think you can. You might use the SQL_VARIANT data type. But it has some drawbacks in some scenarios; you will need to read the MSDN documentation carefully. I would certainly advise to use strict types when possible...

Comment: Yes, sql_variant should be able to hold any data type. I've answered a question that user149691 didn't ask - is it possible to define a stored procedure with an unknown number of parameters, all having different types.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I will go and check out that answer, because I find that interesting too. Thanks for the info. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let we see an example.

```
create table #tbl (id int,val varchar(20))
insert #tbl values(1,'abc'),(2,'def')

create procedure update_tmp
@id int, @val varchar(50)
as
exec sp_executesql N'update #tbl set val=@val where id=@id', -- (1) query to execute
   N'@id int, @val varchar(20)', -- (2) query params declaration
   @id=@id, @val=@val -- (3) param initialization
-- left parts are defined in sp_executesql context, right parts go from outer sp definition

select * from #tbl
```

(1) and (2) can be `@variable`s

Comment: Yes, it is clear. But may you tell - how do sp_executeSql allow to send any datatype as it's parameters? What is the actual type of param1..paramN?

Comment: You describe (define) param types in `(2)`. The types should match underlying data.